# Wolphram|Alpha API Android Exception Error

Tags: java, android, exception, wolframalpha

Hello i am Yassine and i am newbee in android development.
I want to create a simple app that retrieve answers from WolframAlpha website. And i am stuck with lot of errors. 
This is a part of my code:

```
`//Get The Search Input From The Main Activity
String sciSearch = myIntent.getStringExtra(HomeActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    //Call WAengine

            WAEngine engine = new WAEngine();
            Log.d("Engine","Engine Was Created");
            //Check The App Id
            engine.setAppID(appid);
             Log.d("AppId","App Selected");
            engine.addFormat("plaintext");
            //Create A Query
            WAQuery query = engine.createQuery();
//Submit The Query
            query.setInput(sciSearch);
            //Get Results
            //Print The Url
            result  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
            content = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content);
            //String url = engine.toURL(query);
            //result.setText(url);
            //Here is The Problem
            try{
                Log.d("Query Performed","The Query was not performed");
                WAQueryResult queryResult = engine.performQuery(query);
                Log.d("Query Performed","The Query was performed");
                for(WAPod pod : queryResult.getPods()){
                    if(!pod.isError()){
                        Log.d("Pod",pod.getTitle());
                        //result.setText(pod.getTitle());

                             for (WASubpod subpod : pod.getSubpods()) {
                                for (Object element : subpod.getContents()) {
                                    if (element instanceof WAPlainText) {
                                       //content.setText(((WAPlainText) element).getText());
                                        Log.d("Content",((WAPlainText) element).getText());
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    }

                }
            }catch (WAException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }`
```

When i check the Logcat, it logs that the Query Is Not Perfomed for first Error.
Then i got another Error of  'URLFetcher' as a TAG and it says Exception Downloading URL http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query?appid=XXX&input=pi&format=PLAINTEXT&async=false&reinterpret=true
Then another and last Error TAG : EGL_genymotion saying that eglSurfaceAttrib not implmented.
I hope i was clear enough i already checked the url that is requested it returns an xml file so should i just use XmlPullParser to parse it, other than using the default one in the Wolframe library. Sorry if my code is not professional i am still working on my self (Will Do Some Refactoring) :). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found why it was throwing an exception, it turns out that the problem was in the android version that i am compiling for. i had just to add those lines and it works fine.

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder() .detectAll().penaltyLog().build(); 
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

thanks